# Problem with a regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to get this working:

PHP

First match should look for the following:

```
                  $pattern1 = "/<div rawurl\=\"(.*)\" class/"; // Add wildcard here as there will be 10 matches, we are only looking for one.
                  preg_match($pattern1, $file, $out1);
```

Then run a second check to see if our defined variable exists in the result from the first `preg_match` `$out1`,

```
                  $pattern2 = preg_quote("http://domain.com/extras/?possiblequery" ."/");
                  $pattern2 = "/".$pattern2."/";
                  if (preg_match($pattern2, $file, $out)); 
                    { return result
```

I have trouble coding up the regular expression for these two `preg_match` lines... I am pretty sure it's the first one with the wildcard.. Any help is welcome!

Comment: You should not use regex to parse HTML. Use DOMDocument instead: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Change your `.*` to either `.*?` (ungreedy match) or `[^"]*` to match every character up until it hits a quote. This should work fairly well, though (as mentioned every time someone uses "RegEx" and "html" in question ) it's never a good idea to mix the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the delimiters with the second parameter of [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote):

```
preg_quote("http://example.com/extras/?possiblequery", "/")
```

Comment: oh yes! had typed this out a an example, forgot to add that bit, is in the actual code. so its not that. I am sure the problem is somewhere in the first preg_match, to do with the wildcard..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the lack of ’?’ after ’.*’ seems suspect to me.

What do you call a widcard ?